# Prolog, building list with conditional clauses

Tags: if-statement, prolog, conditional-statements

I need to do this homework assignment using prolog (SWI-flavor) and cant get my head around some things.

For example, if i want to iterate through a list and add its elements to another, but ONLY if they meet certain condition, how would I go about it? I can add them all, or none, but if I add clause that checks this condition, the whole recursion turns out as "false". I understand why this is, but have no idea how to fix it. Basically what i want is:

```
goal(Stuff) :- do_something(X),
               only_do_this_if_something(Y),
               always_do_this(Z).
```

Currently, if `only_do_this_if_something(Y)` fails, also `always_do_this(Z)` doesnt happen as the whole goal turns false...

Comment: +1 for being honest about needing help for homework assignment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog loops and conditional statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964420/prolog-loops-and-conditional-statements)

Comment: @GuyC: There is nothing specific to SWI here!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use the if structure:

```
<condition> -> (do_something) ; (do_something else)
```

in this case:

```
goal(Stuff):-
  do_something(X),
  if_something(Y)-> do_this(Y) ; true,
  always_do_this(Z).
```

or you simply write two clauses like:

```
goal(Stuff):-
  do_something(X),
  conditional_stuff(Y),
  always_do_this(Z).

conditional_stuff(Y):-
  condition(Y),
  do_this(Y).

conditional_stuff(_).
```

Comment: Thanks, the first part of this message solved the problem quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following programming pattern, which is used quite a lot in Prolog:

- Iterate through the list, one element at a time
- Set a base case for the recursion
- In one clause, check whether the conditions apply and do something, then continue with recursion
- In the next clause skip the item and continue with recursion

You have to either use the cut (!) to forbid backtracking or explicitly check that the condition do not apply in the latter clause.

Note that you said that you wanted to have an output list with the items for which 'something' applied (which is not what you wrote in your code)...

Applying this pattern to your problem it would look something like this:

```
myRecursion([], []). % This is the base case
myRecursion([Item|Tail], [Item|NTail]):-
  something_applies(...),
  do_something(...),
  only_do_this_if_something(...),
  always_do_this(...).
  myRecursion(Tail, NTail).
myRecursion([Item|Tail], NTail):-
  not(something_applies(...)),
  do_something(...),
  always_do_this(...),
  myRecursion(Tail, NTail).
```

Comment: -1. This is complicated and bug-prone due to the repetition, and completely unnecessary since Prolog has an if-then-else construct.

Comment: I completely disagree with you ;) I believe it is much clearer to have separate clauses for separate actions. The first part of the body of each clause discern between cases and then you just do whatever you want to do in the rest of the clause. Try to understand a piece of code with a couple of if-then-else constructs and I believe you might agree with me. It is ok, however, to use some if-then-elses here and there if they don't affect readability.

Comment: I regularly use the if-then-else construct and find it contributes greatly to my code's clarity *and* speed. Its logical meaning is clearer than that of cut, while it maintains the DRY principle compared to your style.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then what you need is a predicate like `include/3`:

```
include(:Goal, +List1, ?List2)
    Filter elements for which Goal succeeds. True if List2 contains
    those elements Xi of List1 for which call(Goal, Xi) succeeds.
```

Usage example:

```
?- include(number, [a(b), 2, _, 1.2, C, '1'], L).
L = [2, 1.2].
```

Now your homework becomes "how to implement `include/3`". Once you have implemented your version of `include/3` you can check if it matches SWI's version by looking at its source code: `listing(include)`.

Answer (score 0):

try the ignore/1 predicate:

```
goal(Stuff) :-
    do_something(X)
    ignore(only_do_this_if_something(Y)),
    always_do_this(Z).
```

ignore/1 calls the only argument and succeeds whenever it fails or not:

```
ignore(X) :- X, !.
ignore(_).
```