# Finding second min value in list

Tags: prolog

I have defined the predicate that finds the minimum value in list e.g

```
greater(X,Y):- X > Y.
isLower(X,Y):- X < Y.


findmin( [X]   , X ).
findmin( [H|T] , P ):- findmin(T,P1) , isLower(H,P1), P is H.
findmin( [H|T] , P) :- findmin(T,P1) , greater(H , P1), P is P1.
```

However i have hard time modifying this code to find second minimum value including nested lists.

How could i assure that the second minimum value will be returned?

Comment: `find_second_min(L, Min2) :- sort(L, [_, Min2|_]).` ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "including nested lists"? Can you have something like `findmin([1,2,[3,0],4], 0)`?

Answer (score 4):

I mean this mostly as a joke, but here it is:

```
find_second_min(L, Min2) :- sort(L, [_, Min2|_]).
```

So, sorting will definitely put all your items in order. You could get the minimum by just looking at the top one. If you want want the two smallest, you can look at the first two elements:

```
find_mins(L, Min1, Min2) :- sort(L, [Min1, Min2|_]).
```

As you know, sorting is O(N log N) while you can find just the minimum in O(N). So to find just one value this is probably too much work. But it's cute.

Comment: s(X) Of course it is not a joke, this is the only pragmatic and efficient way to do it.

Comment: Be careful, the original question uses arithmetic comparisons, while `sort/2` will use standard order of terms. Some things will sort differently!

Comment: `sort` in Swi-Prolog is a mergesort implemented in C, so it's very fast. However, it's an *O(N log N)* algorithm, and at some point will be slower than a linear algorithm. This point is roughly N=10'000'000 where Willem's solution becomes faster.

Comment: This approach has another weakness in that Prolog bails out with a stack overflow on list sizes larger than 10'000'000. `sort` needs to return a whole new list, after all. It still is by far the shortest and fastest solution for list sizes up to 10m.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply make `P` a list containing the two smallest numbers. Then you would need to check for each element if it is smaller than the larger one in `P`, and if so, replace it. Then in the end, the larger of the two is the second largest element.

By the way, you really don't need to define your own `greater`/`isLower` – why not just use the operators that are built in, `>`/`<` in their place?

This would also make it a bit easier to spot the bug you have in your code if `H` is exactly as large as `P1`.

So, here's how I would do it:

```
find2nd([H1, H2 | T], M) :- H1 < H2, !, find2nd_i(T, M, [H1, H2]).
find2nd([H1, H2 | T], M) :- H1 >= H2, find2nd_i(T, M, [H2, H1]).

find2nd_i([], M2, [_, M2]).
find2nd_i([H | T], M, [M1, M2]) :- H >= M2, !, find2nd_i(T, M, [M1, M2]).
find2nd_i([H | T], M, [M1, M2]) :- H < M2, H >= M1, !, find2nd_i(T, M, [M1, H]).
find2nd_i([H | T], M, [M1, M2]) :- H < M2, H < M1, find2nd_i(T, M, [H, M1]).
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your implementation of `findmin/2` is not very efficient:

```
findmin([H|T],P):- findmin(T,P1) , isLower(H,P1), P is H.
```

Since it does not use *tail recursion*. You better transform this into a clause with tail recursion and an accumulator.

You can - as is suggested by @DanielLyons sort the list and then retrieve the second element, but this requires *O(n log n)* time complexity for the sorting step. The sorting is however done in low level C on most Prolog systems; but eventually, if the list is *very* large, a linear apporach will outperform it.

You can also use @FelixDombek's approach by storing the two values into a list. One can slightly improve the efficiency of this approach by:

- not using a list, but simply two parameters since it will save on pattern matching and tuple construction; and
- use an [*if-then-else*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023717/prolog-building-list-with-conditional-clauses) approach to save on comparisons.

This results in transforming the program into:

```
find2nd([H1,H2|T],Min2) :-
    H1 =< H2 ->
    find2nd(T,H1,H2,Min2)
   ;find2nd(T,H2,H1,Min2).

find2nd([],_,Min2,Min2).
find2nd([H|T],H1,H2,Min2) :-
    H >= H2 ->
    find2nd(T,H1,H2,Min2)
   ;(  H >= H1 ->
       find2nd(T,H1,H,Min2)
      ;find2nd(T,H,H1,Min2)
    ).
```

Comment: +1 for the "code review". I usually shy away from using imperative structures for clearer, more declarative code. But of course it's true that they can be useful optimizations when it comes to speed.

Comment: 2 remarks: (1) there's an error in your last `if` condition `H >= H`, (2) there seem to be other factors at work for very large lists. Even with millions of items to process, the `sort` is way faster than the linear algorithm.

Comment: @FelixDombek: thanks for the bugreport, I fixed it. About efficiency, sorting a list with comparisons cannot be performed better than *O(n log n)*, that's a theoretical result one can easily prove. So eventually an *O(n)* will outperform it. Note however that using an implementation in C will be very efficient compared to an interpreted one in Prolog since the costs of calls and pattern matching can be rather expensive.

Comment: I know this, however, the run time of the linear algorithm does not really scale up linearly. Try it yourself! The discrepancy between the theoretical efficiency and real timing only gets bigger for very large N. That's why there must be other, hidden, factors. I'm thinking about asking a question about that, actually, as it is really kind of strange.

Comment: @FelixDombek: currently I am at work, can you ask a question that shows a benchmark graph, I will try to look at it after working hours.

Comment: It seems I measured the wrong thing. Your answer is the fastest code for N > 10'000'000. I have yet to try this on a x64 Prolog installation with even larger lists, but the biggest drag on performance (with indeed nonlinear run times) were my use of a list. Even with cuts and after getting rid of the list, though, your code is a little bit faster. For N = 10'000'000: yours ~1.742 s, mine(-list) ~1.825 s, `sort` ~1.931 s.

Comment: @FelixDombek: please do not take this answer as an offense to your answer. I upvoted your answer, it is a good one. The purpose of this one was only to show how one could (potentially) optimize it a tiny bit (or at least show some general principles about Prolog optimization). It's not because a certain transformation works good in general that it works in all cases.

Comment: Absolutely no offense taken, I upvoted you too you know! There is nothing ironic in my statement, and I enjoyed the optimization hints. :)