# Conditional Statements in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have just started prolog and was wondering if we can implement conditional statements like(if.else)in Prolog also and if so how??
Can someone implement this code in Prolog just for an example-

```
if(a==2)
 print("A is 2");
if(a==3)
 print("A is 3");
else
 print("HAhahahahaah");
```

Ok so I am doing this after Sergey Dymchenko answer.

```
Test(A) :-read(A),
 ( A =:= 2 ->
    write('A is 2')
 ;
    ( A =:= 3 ->
        write('A is 3')
    ;
        write('HAhahahahaah')
    )
 ).
```

This is giving right answer except this is displaying A = 2 also which I dont want(If I give input 2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog loops and conditional statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964420/prolog-loops-and-conditional-statements)

Comment: @david Sorry but I am facing difficulty understanding it.Can you or someone please post a code where this is implemented.it would be easier to understand with a code..

Comment: I don't speak prolog, but also look at [Prolog, conditional clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023717/prolog-conditional-clauses?lq=1)

Comment: After you updated the question with `read(Term). f(Term)==f(2) :- write('Hello world!').` I see that my answer will not help you. Consider reading some introductory Prolog text like "Learn Prolog Now!" http://www.learnprolognow.org/ first.

Comment: @Sergey Yeah I am reading from the same book you suggested.Can you help me a bit in taking input,I think I am going wrong there

Comment: @Quantum Your code is wrong on many levels. For ones, it's not syntactically correct. Read more about Prolog and try to do some exercises from "Learn Prolog Now!".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
test(A) :-
    (   A =:= 2 ->
        write('A is 2')
    ;   A =:= 3 ->
        write('A is 3')
    ;   write('HAhahahahaah')
    ).
```

Another way to do it:

```
test(2) :-
    write('A is 2').
test(3) :-
    write('A is 3').
test(A) :-
    A \= 2, A \= 3,
    write('HAhahahahaah').
```

There are differences with these two codes, like choice points, behavior when A is not instantiated, and if A is treated as a number or not. But both will work the same way (except choice points left) and as expected with queries `test(2).`, `test(3).`, `test(42).`

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot I found the problem with my code.Here is now what I am doing-
    `Test(A) :-read(A),
     ( A =:= 2 ->
        write('A is 2')
     ;
         ( A =:= 3 ->
             write('A is 3')
         ;
             write('HAhahahahaah')
         )
     ). `
But This is also printing value of A also in the end.
example if user gives 3 output is
    A is 3
     A = 3

Can I remove A=3 from the output???

Comment: Sergey, you don't need the extra parenthesis in your first solution. The first level of parenthesis is considered good programming style. The others do nothing and only clutter the solution.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing Sergey's solution and remove the unnecessary parenthesis.

Comment: @PauloMoura I follow the ECLiPSe style guide recommendation "If-then-elses should always be parenthesised." http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/applications/tutorial011.html#toc53
And I think it's much easier to see the nested structure this way.

Comment: Hi Sergey. That rule is meant to refer to only the outermost parenthesis. Is more general, however: it's considered good style (and helps avoid bugs in code) also to always enclose disjunction between parenthesis.

Comment: @PauloMoura I don't think so. It says "always", without mentioning exceptions. And there is also "Always put semicolons at the start of a new line, aligned with the opening and closing parentheses."

Comment: @PauloMoura I've checked ECLiPSE sources (the specific file I've looked at was b_trees.ecl), and sometimes they format nested ifs the way you suggested, and sometimes the other way.

Comment: You're misinterpreting that style rule (whose text, admittedly, could be improved). See e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2899.pdf (page 10).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61797/discussion-between-sergey-dymchenko-and-paulo-moura).